# Plot a list of functions in a single graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, functions, procedural-programming

I am trying to solve a problem using Procedural programming paradigm in Mathematica.

I want to find a way to plot a list of functions in a single graph.

The code is as follow, let me know what is wrong.

```
Show[Plot[Do[L[i], {i, 0, n}]], {xo, -20, 20}]
```

where L[i] is list of functions, n is the number of elements of the plot and xo is the variable on which all the functions as the elements of L[i] are dependent on.
When I plot each element of L, Mathematica shows the plot but not in this case where I want to plot them all together.

I have tried debugging, does'nt help. I do not want to use Table[] as it will be digressing away from Procedural Programming, as I am trying to write a code for a course.

Comment: `Do` does not return results for each iteration. You'd need [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead. If you really wanted a procedural approach, you'd probably do something along the lines of `plots={};Do[AppendTo[plots,Plot[...]],{i,0,n}];...` which is arguably worse than just using `Table`

Comment: The first rule of debugging in Mathematica: try each part of your input separately and see if it returns what you expected.  See what `Do[L[i], {i, 0, n}]` returns (answer: nothing). Look up `Table`.

Comment: @Chetan see: [merging-accounts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), looks like you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Sinh[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Or

```
Grid[{Plot[#[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {Sin, Cos, Sinh}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it is already mentioned by @Szabolcs `Table` is a much better choice for what you want.

However, if you necessarily want to take the procedural way, keep in mind that loops make operations specified inside, but return nothing. Indeed, the following operation:

```
    lst = {};

Do[AppendTo[lst, Sin[i*x]], {i, 0, 5}]
```

return nothing. Try to evaluate it.

However, a list, `lst`, has already been created, as you can make sure by evaluating it:

```
lst

(* {0, Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin[5 x]}  *)
```

Thus, to plot it you simply evaluate the following:

```
Plot[lst, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!